# Evaluating $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\cos(x)dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

By integrating over the contour around an appropriate sector, how does one solve  $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\cos(x)dx$$

Comment: Doesn't seem like you need a countour: $$e^{-x}\cos x = \frac 12\left(e^{-x+ix} + e^{-x-ix}\right)$$ Or just do integration by parts twice.

Comment: If you do the integration by parts, won't you get a problem with the [(-e^(-x))cos(x)] when you insert infinity? and the same with [(e^(-x))sin(x)]?

Comment: Well, do the indefinite integral, first. Then compute the limit.

Comment: Thanks! but if I want to use the contour, how should i proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the integral
\begin{align}
\int_{C} e^{-|z|} \, e^{iz} dz
\end{align}
with a contour enclosing no poles.

Answer (score -4):

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}F(x)-F(0)$$

Comment: I didn't know if she had a problem finding the primitive function or if it was the infinity thing that was causing issues and Thomas Andrews had already showed how to find the primitive function.

Comment: If you want to know why this (as originally written) was wrong, then you can ask a question. As it is now, it is at least true, if not at all helpful for the question at hand. (Modulo the assumption that $F'(x)=f(x)$, which you merely assume above.)

Comment: And your name doesn't give one a reason to want to help you. People who are constantly putting themselves down are a drag to try to teach, and they are likely to start putting other people down, when push comes to shove...

Comment: Calm down, it was a typo, I understand why it was wrong. I don't have any reason to put anyone down.

Comment: I wasn't saying you were putting people down. You asked for help, and I wanted you to realize that the negativity of your name is a strong indicator that might drive people who want to help you away. You might not realize what the negativity signifies - you might think of it as just a joke. That is not necessarily how it reads to other people, however.