# Evaluating $\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x}\sin (x)\;dx$

Tags: integration

How to calculate $\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x}\sin (x)\;dx$?

Is it by parts? But I ended up with the same integration repeated, so what shall I do?

Comment: Perhaps it is easier to integrate $e^{-x}\cos x+ie^{-x}\sin x$

Comment: If it happens to repeat, you can treat it as an equation:$$\int f(x)dx= \text{something}+\alpha\int f(x)dx\iff(1-\alpha)\int f(x)=\text{something}$$

Comment: The Wikipedia article on integration by parts has a example for a [similar integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Exponentials_and_trigonometric_functions).

Comment: [Very similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970932/evaluating-int-0-infty-e-x-cosxdx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will integration by parts twice in a row:

1)$ \text{First time } (f=\sin(x), g'=e^{-x} \Leftrightarrow f'=\cos(x), g=-e^{-x}$):

$$\int e^{-x} \sin(x) dx = -e^{-x} \sin(x) - \int -e^{-x} \cos(x)$$

2)$ \text{Second time } (f=\cos(x), g'=-e^{-x} \Leftrightarrow f'=-\sin(x), g=e^{-x}$):

$$- e^{-x} \sin(x) - \int - e^{-x} \cos(x) = - e^{-x} \sin(x) - (e^{-x} \cos(x) - \int -e^{-x} \sin(x))$$

So now we get:

$$\int e^{-x} \sin(x) dx = - e^{-x} \sin(x) - (e^{-x} \cos(x) + \int e^{-x} \sin(x))$$
$$2 \int e^{-x} \sin(x) dx = - e^{-x} \sin(x) - e^{-x} \cos(x) $$
$$ \int e^{-x} \sin(x) dx = \frac{- e^{-x} \sin(x) - e^{-x} \cos(x)}{2} $$

Now you can evaluate the integral for the final answer:

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \sin(x) dx = \frac{1}{2} $$

Answer (score 3):

$$I=\Im \left( \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(1+i)x} dx\right)=\Im \left(  \frac{e^{-(1+i)x}}{-1+i}||^{\infty}_0\right)=\Im \left(\frac{1}{1-i}\right)=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know Laplace transformation, simply using partial integration yields the same.

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \sin(x) dx = - e^{-x} \cos(x) \mid_{0}^{\infty} - \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \cos(x) dx = [0-(-1)] - \left[ e^{-x} \sin(x) \mid_{0}^{\infty} + \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \sin(x) dx\right] = 1 - \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \sin(x) dx
\end{align*}

This is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
2 \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \sin(x) dx = 1
\end{align*}

which yields the solution 
\begin{align*}
 \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \sin(x) dx = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

One way is to complex the integral, and your answer will be Im($\int e^{(i-1)x} dx$). But if you don't know how to do that, I will explain it with integration by parts.

$$\int e^{-x} \sin x = - \sin x e^{-x} + \int e^{-x} \cos x \text{ (1)}$$
Use integration by parts on the second integral.

$$\int e^{-x} \cos x = - \cos x e^{-x} - \int \sin x e^{-x}$$

So $$\int \sin x e^{-x} = - \cos x e^{-x} - \int e^{-x} \cos x$$.

Add this to $(1)$ to get

$$2I = -e^{-x}(\sin x + \cos x) \Rightarrow I = -\frac{1}{2} e^{-x} (\sin x + \cos x)$$

You can then plug in the bounds.

Answer (score 0):

IBP of the initial integral (integrating $e^{-x}$ and differentiating $\sin(x)$) gives you,

$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x} \sin(x) dx = \int_0^\infty e^{-x} \cos(x) dx.
$$

Integrating the RHS by parts gives

$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x} \cos(x) dx = 1 - \int_0^\infty e^{-x} \sin(x) dx.
$$

Plugging the second into the first gives

$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x} \sin(x) dx = 1 - \int_0^\infty e^{-x} \sin(x) dx.
$$

Rearranging the above equation for the integral in question gives

$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x} \sin(x) dx = \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Recognizing this as a Laplace transform,

$$\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x}\sin x \;dx = \left.\mathcal{L}(\sin x)\right|_{s=1} = \left. \frac{1}{1+s^2}\right|_{s=1}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Or you could integrate by parts twice.  Either function can take the role of $u$ or $dv$ in $$\int u \, dv = uv-\int v\, du.$$

Method I:  $u=e^{-x}$ and $dv=\sin x \, dx$.

Method II:  $u=\sin x$ and $dv=e^{-x} \, dx$.

Either way works.

Answer (score 0):

Using integration by parts we have:

$$\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x}\sin (x)\;dx=\lim_{b\to\infty}e^{-x}\sin\left(x\right)\Big|_0^b+\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\cos\left(x\right)dx$$$$=\lim_{b\to\infty}-e^{-x}\sin\left(x\right)\Big|_0^b+\left(\lim_{b\to\infty}-e^{-x}\cos\left(x\right)\Big|_0^b-\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\sin\left(x\right)dx\right)$$

So :$$\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x}\sin (x)\;dx=1/2$$